# R conditionally remove data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I have imported a xlsx file into R and loaded each sheet into separate data frames. As this is a big workbook with redundant sheet I need to conditionally remove some from the global environment. The end goal is to keep only sheets which will be used to automate time series analysis.

I would like to remove all data frames from which do not meet the suffix criteria. The current code I have which runs but doesn't appear to do anything is:

```
for(i in ls()) {
 if(substring(ls()[i], regexpr(pattern = "_", mget(ls()[i]))+1) != "E10" |
  substring(ls()[i], regexpr(pattern = "_", mget(ls()[i]))+1) != "U91" |
  substring(ls()[i], regexpr(pattern = "_", mget(ls()[i]))+1) != "V95" |
  substring(ls()[i], regexpr(pattern = "_", mget(ls()[i]))+1) != "V98") {
    remove(ls()[i])

   }
}
```

Would this also take care of data frames which do not have have suffixes example "Sheet127" ?

Appreciate your assistance

Comment: Please provide a Minimum reproducible example.

Comment: A common refrain on SO answers is that you're very very often better off making a list of data frames rather than saving lots of similar data frames into your environment. This is one of the situations where managing your data will be much easier if you have all the data frames in one list

Comment: Hi camille, thankyou for the reply. I can see your point given that there are way too many data frames in my environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using a deviation of @Patrick Rutz answer:

```
rm(list = ls(pattern = '^.*([^E10|U91|V95|V98])$'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the list and pattern arguments of rm() and ls() respectively.

This should work.

```
rm(list = ls(pattern = '^.*(E10|U91|V95|V98)$'))
```

Comment: could you explain what does '^.* does?

Comment: In this context it means the beginning of the token/string. It's better to be explicit because you wouldn't want to default to "contains" behavior looking for a suffix. It's the opposite of $ in regex.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for the reply. This actually removed the one's I wanted to keep. I will simply manipulate the pattern inputs. Thankyou for the reply